# VSTS Build and Selenium

Tags: selenium, azure-devops

I am attempting to use Selenium to do some UI testing for a .net web app i am working on. 
Every build fails with ether no Tests to run in the new configuration or #[warning]DistributedTests: Error : Test run directory 'C:\temp\' does not contain any assemblies that match the specified criteria: '***test*.dll'. Verify that the test run directory contains the target assemblies and the source filter is correct.  in the deprecated version.

the test runs correctly when run from Visual Studio

Comment: Sounds like your test config in VSTS is pointing to an invalid directory. It's looking in C:\temp for test dlls?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the test location is wrong, you need to specify the correct test location that contains the test assembly files (the path need to be accessible from test machine you specified).

Check Test Drop Location value if you are using Run Functional Tests task.